# Able to decrypt previously encrypted messages without passphrase, but can't export GPG private key

Tags: encryption, gnupg, private-key

I feel really stupid asking this, but why not. I have a bunch of files I encrypted a while ago with a `gpg` key pair that is password protected. Since then, I've forgotten the password. But the key must still be somewhere (my keyring?), because I'm successfully able to decrypt all files with `gpg -d file.gpg` *without* any password prompt.

However, when I try to export the private key, I'm asked for a password.

I've tried rebooting to see if it's a temporary thing, but it's not. When I cold reboot and try to decrypt an encrypted message, it works. When I try to export the private key, no luck.

I'm assuming `gpg-agent` is caching something; I've tried to run `gpg` through `strace` to try and retrieve my private key, but I've had no luck there. `gpg` reads the password-protected private key file, talks to `gpg-agent`, and receives the decrypted message back. But I can't find the private key (or maybe I don't know what to look for) anywhere in the `strace` logs.

I've tried talking to `gpg-agent` with `gpg-connect-agent`, but I'm not sure what to do there to get the cached private key.

After decrypting, I've safely stored all the messages somewhere, so data loss isn't an issue anymore. I'm just wondering if generating a new key-pair is my only option.

Comment: Are you sure it's not asking you for password to _re-encrypt_ the exported key?

Comment: What version of GnuPG are you using? 1.6, or 2.0, or 2.1+?

Comment: GnuPG 2.2.7. Pretty sure it's (`gpg --export-secret-keys -a "My Name"`) not asking the passphrase to re-encrypt the exported key because I get "Bad passphrase (try 2 of 3)" when I give a new passphrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each OpenPGP "key" consists of several independent keypairs (subkeys), usually for different purposes (e.g. one certification & signing subkey, one encryption subkey, etc.).

In GnuPG 2.1 and later, private keys are stored in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d` and managed by *gpg-agent*. There is a separate file for each subkey, encrypted with your passphrase. This means that you can easily bypass gpg-agent, but even if you do, you still cannot unlock the key files without knowing your passphrase.

Technically, each key file can be encrypted using a different passphrase (although gpg's UI doesn't normally offer that). For that reason, when gpg-agent stores your passphrases in e.g. GNOME Keyring, they are also stored separately for each subkey without checking if they're identical.

So it's possible that your passphrase was only "remembered" for the encryption subkey, but not for the signing subkey. Since they're identical, it should be enough to just retrieve the stored pass­phrase from GNOME Keyring.

Use `secret-tool` to search GNOME Keyring for your passphrases, and see if any of them work:

```
$ secret-tool search --all xdg:schema org.gnupg.Passphrase
```

(You could also use GNOME's graphical program *Seahorse* aka "Passwords & Keys", but it tends to crash or freeze and so isn't nearly as useful.)

Comment: Thank you so much, you're awesome! This retrieved the secret passphrase :) Marked as accepted answer.